# Constantly call / return a Meteor.method

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a list of 600 url's that i want to loop over requests to.

Would it be possible to `console.log` the content of each one as i receive it as opposed to waiting for the 600 to finish then return it all as 1?

Sorry if this seems a bit vague, not sure on the correct terms to use to describe this.

```
  Meteor.methods({
    getNations: function () {
      this.unblock();

      var result = Meteor.http.get('https://www.easports.com/uk/fifa/ultimate-team/api/fut/item?jsonParamObject=%7B%22page%22:1%7D');

      var totalPages = JSON.parse(result.content).totalPages;

      for (var i = 1; i < totalPages; i++) {
        try {
          var page = Meteor.http.get('https://www.easports.com/uk/fifa/ultimate-team/api/fut/item?jsonParamObject=%7B%22page%22:' + i + '%7D');

          console.log(JSON.parse(page.content));
        } catch(e) {
          console.log('Cannot get page', e);
        }
      }

      return result;
    }
  })
```

Comment: You can loop over each url, fetch the contents, print them, then move on to the next url? Since you have provided no code or anything, it's hard to give any direct help.

Comment: I added a code example if that helps

Comment: Sorry not really sure what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to:
- Fire all requests at once
- console log them as they return
- return all the results to the client?

What output do you get from the current code?

Comment: That's a fair point, i wanna be `console.log()`'ing on the client side but i don't wanna Http from there as it will just lock me up. I wouldn't wanna output 600 eventually i wanna insert them into the Mongodb. The `console.log()` is just for debugging help

Comment: @datacarl no, i am firing them synchrously but i'd like to `console.log()` to the client console when i get the result from each one

Comment: Ah ok. A method can only return once, so either you call the method multiple times from the client, or you have to fire all the http requests at once from the server (you could ofc do that in sync too, but would take a while with 600 requests) and return them.

(I realised that I assumed that the 600 requests are the totalPages count, is that right?)

Comment: Yea the totalPages is 627 (around 600). If i called it from the server side and put the results into a databaes would the Meteor front end reactively update with the new documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get all the pages, insert them into a collection and make them available on the client. There are a few caveats though. If you call the method multiple times you will get duplicates in the database, not sure if that's what you intended. Also, the error logging only happens on the server and is never displayed to the client, dont know if that's what you want either. Note that the second `Meteor.http.get` is passed a callback which makes it [run async](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call).

```
# Shared code
Nations = new Mongo.Collection('nations')

# Server

Meteor.methods({
  getNations: function () {
    this.unblock();

    var result = Meteor.http.get('https://www.easports.com/uk/fifa/ultimate-team/api/fut/item?jsonParamObject=%7B%22page%22:1%7D');

    var totalPages = JSON.parse(result.content).totalPages;

    var callback = function(err, page) {
      if (err) 
        console.log('Cannot get page', e);
      else
        Nations.insert(page);
    }
    for (var i = 1; i < totalPages; i++) {
      Meteor.http.get('https://www.easports.com/uk/fifa/ultimate-team/api/fut/item?jsonParamObject=%7B%22page%22:' + i + '%7D', callback);
    }

    return result;
  }
});

Meteor.publish('nations', function() {
  return Nations.find();
});

# Client
Meteor.subscribe('nations');
```

Comment: Yea this is what my end goal would be, given Meteor's reactive nature if i showed the collections on the frontend would they get spat out to the front end as they got created in the database?

Comment: Yea i had a play around with it, i got it to get it working once but after that, not so much.. I think i'll just focus on something more simple in Meteor so i can learn the ins and outs of it a bit more. I'll mark it as accepted as this answers my question mainly. I only wanted to `console.log()` for debug purposes. The end goal was to do what you do here